# Determine which side of SCNBox got touched, Scene Kit ios

Tags: objective-c, 3d, touch, scenekit

I am using Scene Kit and have created an SCNBox. On the front face of the box I want it so "A" happens if the left side of the front face gets clicked, and "B" happens if the right side of the front face gets clicked. How can I achieve this. I checked on stack but most answers cover if a node gets touched, not part of a node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [identify face of a cube hit on touches began in Swift-Scene Kit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153302/identify-face-of-a-cube-hit-on-touches-began-in-swift-scene-kit)

Answer (score 6):

[`SCNHitTestResult`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnhittestresult) has a [`geometryIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnhittestresult/1522625-geometryindex) that will give you the index of the geometry *element* that was hit (i.e. the cube face). It also has a [`faceIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnhittestresult/1522888-faceindex) property that will give you the index of the primitive in this element.

Comment: Is it also valid to use the `localNormal` value for a `SCNBox`?

Comment: Please could anyone explain to me what is meant by "index of the primitive" for the "faceIndex" property?

Comment: A `SCNGeometryElement` is made of several [primitives](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometryprimitivetype) (triangles, quads, etc.) and `faceIndex` gives you the index (in the range `[0, primitiveCount-1]`) for the primitive that was hit