# SceneKit - Detect Touch on Different Objects of 3D model

Tags: objective-c, scenekit, 3dsmax

I have a **3D** model i downloaded from net as free. It is a **3D** cube and it is in **.obj** format. In Xcode it is shown as one object and it have different materials inside it. Now my question is that can i detect touch on materials as i can detect on Nodes?

If not then is Designed Model needed to be different nodes of things making up one single object?

I have no idea of designing a 3D object. Need any idea for Development or Design end.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070840/determine-which-side-of-scnbox-got-touched-scene-kit-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153302/identify-face-of-a-cube-hit-on-touches-began-in-swift-scene-kit

Comment: Thanks @mnuages that solved my problem :)